# SpriteKit RGBA444_COMPRESSED doubles the size on screen

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, ios7.1

I am running a SpriteKit game on iPhone4, iOS7.1
When I select the regular RGBA888 texture atlas format  it looks good, however, when I try to use RGBA444_COMPRESSED, all atlas textures are double the size as if the display is not retina.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you show us your two types of images and how you set the texture of your sprites, I think more people are able to help.

Comment: It is a normal atlas initiation, nothing special about it. Just don't look right on iPhone 4 / iOS7.1

Comment: what is the texture atlas width and height

Comment: Most of them are 4" size: 640 × 1136, on iOS 8.4/4S it works great.