# TextureAtlas RGBA4444_COMPRESSED not working in ios7.1

Tags: sprite-kit, ios7.1, iphone-4, texture-atlas

I have created a SpriteKit game, and trying to use RGBA444_COMPRESSED texture atlas as per Apple best-practice. 
However, on iOS7.1 / iPhone4 images from texture atlas appear double the size on the screen and not rendered correctly.

I could not find any workaround for this . Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SpriteKit RGBA444\_COMPRESSED doubles the size on screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467883/spritekit-rgba444-compressed-doubles-the-size-on-screen)

Comment: So this is not happening if you use RGBA8888_COMPRESSED or just RGBA8888 format in Output Texture Atlas Format section ?

Comment: I does happen on every compression I am running. As if iOS7.1 does not know how to read the compression.

Comment: are you including both the regular and @2x files of your images for your atlas?

Comment: No. only the @2x, is this not enough for iPhone4?